# Should I use a fan or fume extractor for soldering?

Tags: soldering

I have been starting to solder about once every two weeks. I haven't used any sort of fume extraction or fan, but reading about the health risks, I now understand how important it is to get those fumes away from you. I have some 120mm computer fans lying around that could scatter the fumes and blow them away. Is this adequate for soldering, or should I really just get a fume extractor? I really don't want to spend 50 dollars one one, so I want people's opinions on this. If I only solder occasionally, and use a fan to blow the fumes, do I need a fume extractor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would always go for a fume extractor. For irregular soldering, most people don't use one, but really if you want to reduce the long term health risks then it is always better to get an extractor rather than just try to blow the fumes away. You could never be sure where the fans are actually blowing the fumes, the harmful chemicals could still be in the air. However, you can use all those fans to build your own fume extractor.

There are lots of tutorials on YouTube and Google on how to build your own fume extractor for soldering that don't cost much money! This is the best way to do it in my opinion! Saves money and gives you a bit of a project to work on too

Comment: [Link for the lazy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z64-RwxSztU). Could be quite a fun project.

Comment: I built mine myself. Quite enjoyed doing it too!

Comment: The DIY Perks video said to vent the air outside using ducting. Should I actually do that or should I use a carbon filter like most other fume extractors you can buy?

Comment: Either really. Stick a vent to the outside to get rid of it or use a filter if there is no convenient window nearby